# @Autowired not working in the RESTFul web service Request

Tags: java, spring, web-services, hibernate, rest

I'm using RESTFul webservice with spring hibernate project.I call a webservice with a method but i can't call the @service layer UserService  bean which is null. here my webservice Class.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;
import com.ontag.circa.domain.User;
import com.ontag.circa.service.UserService;`enter code here`

@Component
@Path("/users")
@WebService
public class UserServiceWS extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    User user=new User();

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @WebMethod
    public String addUserDeatails(MultivaluedMap<String, String> userParams) {

            user.setUsername(userParams.getFirst("username"));                  
            user.setGcmid(userParams.getFirst("gcmid"));
            user.setPassword(userParams.getFirst("password"));

            userService.addUserDeatails(user);

        return "Sucesss !!!!!!!!";

    }
}
```

The @Autowired annotation is not working .please provide the solution

Here my Dependencies

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.11</version>
        </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
            </dependency>
          <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
            </dependency>


           <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
          </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ganyo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.11.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.11.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


            <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>        
    </servlet-mapping>

     <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.ontag.circa.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here   spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


     <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ontag.circa.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ontag.circa.service">
<!--    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="javax.jws.WebService"/> -->
    </context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ontag.circa.rest"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">  
            <list>  
                <value>com.ontag.circa.domain.User</value>  
                <value>com.ontag.circa.domain.GCM_Message</value> 
                <value>com.ontag.circa.domain.Ad_geo</value>  
                <value>com.ontag.circa.domain.Advertisement</value> 
                <value>com.ontag.circa.domain.Geofence</value>  

            </list>  
        </property> 
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageDaoImpl" class="com.ontag.circa.dao.MessageDaoImpl" />
    <bean id="userDaoImpl" class="com.ontag.circa.dao.UserDaoImpl" />
    <bean id="userServiceImpl_1" class="com.ontag.circa.service.UserServiceImpl_1" />
    <bean id="userServiceImpl" class="com.ontag.circa.rest.UserServiceWS" />
    <bean id="advertisement" class="com.ontag.circa.service.AdvertisementService" />
    <bean id="messageService" class="com.ontag.circa.service.MessageService" />
</beans>
```

//// this is my Interface

```
   public interface UserService {

        public String addUserDeatails(User user);
        public String getsomevalue(String mess);

    }

    // this is my implementation class
    import javax.transaction.Transactional;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import com.ontag.circa.domain.User;

    @Repository
    public class UserDaoImpl  implements UserDao  {

        @Autowired
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public String addUserDeatails(User user)
        {
            Session session=null;

                    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();                    
                    session.saveOrUpdate(user);
                    tx.commit();



            return "Succes fully Added the Web service";
        }

        public String getsomevalue(String mess)
        {
            System.out.println(mess   +   "   "   + mess);


            return "message";
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seams that you are using JAX-RS along with Spring. Are you sure that you have followed the integration instructions of your JAX-RS implementation with Spring correctly?

Comment: I don't have an idea  about JAX-RS.I used JAX-WS .Please provide some guidelines that will help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you please show the dependencies you are using?

Comment: I have updated my dependencies under question.

Comment: You are using Jersey as your JAX-RS implementation. You should search it's documentation (make sure to read Jersey 1.x documentation) for how to integration with Spring

Comment: I don't think the Spring integration is available in 1.x.

Comment: Please provide your web.xml as that will be where you've configured the servlet that interprest the class as well as the spring config

Comment: @kajanthan, add `UserService` class

Comment: Could you show us the spring configuration (XML/Java)

Comment: I'm not seeing your ContextLoaderListener that bootstraps the spring application from the applicationContext.xml (i.e. no reference to your applicationContext in your web.xml)

Comment: @rhinds I updated the Spring configuration file

Comment: @MichaelWiles  sorry my spring configuration file name spring-config.xml

Comment: @kajanthan, is there any class that implements `UserService` interface? As the `@Autowired` is not working, are you getting any exceptions in logs?

Comment: @MichaelWiles After adding ContextLoaderListener,its working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. After checking very things,  i see a problem in a class that i define as a bean. some of classes have a special annotation or method that cause spring fail when create bean for that class.